# CDK v2 import table TS

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

```
import { TableV2 } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
>>>
aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb"' has no exported member named 'TableV2'. Did you mean 'Table'?
```

The documentation shows: TypeScript aws-cdk-lib » aws_dynamodb

and 'aws-cdk-lib/aws_dynamodb' is not recognized.

So how do I import [TableV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb-readme.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade CDK to the latest version.  The TableV2 construct was added as a new feature in [v2.95.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.95.0).

Check your current CDK version with `cdk --version`.